# Site cannot be reached after installing centos 7

Tags: centos, hostname

I have a server on centOs 7 with the ip as `192.0.2.123` and host name as `www.example.com`.

now when i `www.example.com` hit the hostname in the browser i am getting

```
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
```

Some times

```
This site can’t be reached

www.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Are there any steps to map ip to hostname.

Comment: you should either use an exisiting dns server of ur own environement , or use google public dns `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

You must a have a valid dns server to be used for name resolution. If you are using Linux , it is simple , just clean up the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and use google public dns server entries in it.

```
nameserver  8.8.8.8
nameserver  8.8.4.4
```

For Windows users see these steps:
[steps-windows](https://www.wiknix.com/how-to-fix-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-in-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Something about your networking is broken. Probably wrong DNS server (should get it via DHCP if configured automatically, else in `/etc/resolv.conf` if configured by hand), or the server is busted, or the target has it's DNS records messed up.

Try the following:

```
host -d www.example.com
```

Gives some "debugging" output, might give clues.

Could also try asking another DNS server:

```
dig www.example.com ANY      # Configured
dig @8.8.8.8 www.example.com # Google's
```

This gives more detail, and tells you (2nd line) if the domain `www.example.com` works ar all. (dig isn't usually installed by default).